# ListView с возможностью перетаскивания элементов

Tags: java, android

Вот увидел такое ListView и мне нужно сделать аналогичное. Что-бы пользователь мог задавать порядок элементов списка путем перетаскивание. Есть ли готовое решение или может как-то можно самому написать?

[image: ListView]

Comment: Мне попадалось такое приложение https://github.com/rubenroy/Minimal-Todo -- иногда его использую для простых туду-списков. Можешь подглядеть, как там сделано, но, правда, там на основе RecyclerView, а не ListView.

Comment: Есть как [множество уже готовых библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=listview+drag+drop&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults), так и на основе их исходного кода вы можете сделать свое решение при желании. ключевые слова для поиска дополнительной информации - ListView (RecyclerView) drag and drop

Comment: Использовал https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview  на основе RecyclerView много всего умеет и можно настраивать под себя.

Comment: [Хороший туториал](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.ktumj5a21) на основе RecyclerView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview сделана именно для вашего функционала. Она достаточно популярная и проверенная.

Интерфейс у неё полностью кастомизируемый. Выглядит список примерно так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: после фразы "Она достаточно популярная и проверенная" вероятно надо было добавить "была в 2013 году...."

Comment: @ermak0ff Вы знаете более новую библиотеку с 1589 форков ?

Comment: нет не знаю) просто стало интересно может есть какие то более новые решения.
ну если же она действительно хорошо кастомизуется, то действительно, самое оптимальное решение.